# Add a common argument to all the methods in a class

Tags: python, arguments

I have three methods in a class,

```
class A:
  def func_1(self, a: int, b: int):
    print(a, b)
  def func_2(self, a: int, c: int):
    print(a, c)
  def func_3(self, a: int, d: int):
    print(a, d)
```

I want to avoid repeating `a: int` again and again, is there a way I could add `a` as a parameter with type annotation `int` to all three methods?

as of now I have a setup like this,

```
def cls_decorator(cls):
  for key, value in cls.__dict__.items():
    if callable(value):
      print(key, value, value.__dict__) # need to add `a: int` to functions here
  return cls

@cls_decorator
class A:
   ...
```

Comment: Why do all of these methods have the same parameter? Is it *semantically* equivalent in each method? *Why isn't it stored as an attribute* of the instances, instead, if it has to be provided for every method call?

Comment: it cannot be an attribute, I am using it to request body of type `int` in fastapi, each method is an endpoint

Comment: What is the rule that tells you which methods need this parameter? I assume, for example, that `__init__` should not have it added. A problem like this could be solved by decorating the methods that need the extra parameter, but that obviously does not avoid the repeated work and in fact adds a ton of complexity. So we need some other way to identify which methods to patch.

Comment: I have made a class decorator which would apply to all the methods, `__init__` could be excluded, it would not be a problem, but will I have to change the `__code__` attribute of methods to add an argument to them?